# Transform array of objects with while and reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I need help with transforming an array of objects. So far I have managed to get all the dates between the initial (begin) and the end (end).

This is what I receive and try to transform.

```js
 const fetchedOffers = [{
    _id: 'dsd87878',
    professional: 'd2ycdd',
    specialty: '704505',
    begin: new Date('2020-04-10T07:00:00.169Z'),
    end: new Date('2020-04-11T21:00:00.169Z'),
    interval: 1200000,
  },
  {
    _id: 'ddd67878',
    professional: '25c0a8',
    specialty: '704505',
    begin: new Date('2020-06-29T08:00:00.169Z'),
    end: new Date('2020-06-30T12:00:00.169Z'),
    interval: 1200000,
  }
];

const hours = fetchedOffers.reduce((prev, acc) => {
  let currentDate = acc.begin.getTime()
  const endDate = acc.end.getTime()

  while (currentDate < endDate) {
    const d = new Date(currentDate)
    if (d.getHours() > 7 && d.getHours() < 20 && d.getDay() < 6 && d.getDay() > 0) {
      prev.push({
        date: new Date(d).toLocaleString('es-CL')
      })
    }
    currentDate = currentDate + acc.interval
  }
  return prev
}, [])
  console.log(hours)
```

The idea is that you can generate an array of objects like this:

```js
    [
      {
        professional: 'd2ycdd',
        specialty: '704505',
        date: [
          {
            offer: 'dsd87878',
            date: '4/10/2020',
            hours: ['07:00', '07:20', '07:40', '08:00',...]
          },
          {
            offer: 'dsd87878',
            date: '4/11/2020',
            hours: [..., '20:00', '20:20', '20:40', '21:00']
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        professional: '25c0a8',
        specialty: '704505',
        date: [
          {
            offer: 'ddd67878',
            date: '6/29/2020',
            hours: ['08:00', '08:20', '08:40', '09:00',...]
          },
          {
            offer: 'ddd67878',
            date: '6/30/2020',
            hours: [..., '11:00', '11:20', '11:40', '12:00']
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
```

I want to group by professional id and by date (no time). Each date is obtained starting with the beginning date (begin) and adding the interval until reaching the end date. In addition I have added other conditions when displaying the hours, for example omitting hours between 20 and 7 hours and also only from Monday to Friday.

How can I do that? So far I only get all the dates between the start and end date but I need to group by dates and professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would tell [reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) is not right method here, you probably want complex transformation.

Check time zones too or use some lib ([moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)?), some dates may be in local, UTC, etc. Made I/O hour values (strings) in snippet look same.

```js
const fetchedOffers = [{
    _id: 'dsd87878',
    professional: 'd2ycdd',
    specialty: '704505',
    begin: new Date('2020-04-10T07:00:00.169Z'),
    end: new Date('2020-04-11T21:00:00.169Z'),
    interval: 1200000,
  },
  {
    _id: 'ddd67878',
    professional: '25c0a8',
    specialty: '704505',
    begin: new Date('2020-06-29T08:00:00.169Z'),
    end: new Date('2020-06-30T12:00:00.169Z'),
    interval: 1200000,
  }
];

let res = [];
document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(
    createNewOffers(fetchedOffers, res)
).replace(/,/g, ',\n').replace(/(["0-9:]{7}),\n/g, '$1,');
function createNewOffers(fetchedOffers, res) {
    for(var acc of fetchedOffers) {
        let currentDate = acc.begin;
        currentDate = currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() + currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
        let endDate = acc.end;
        endDate = endDate.setHours(endDate.getHours() + endDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
        let date = [null, null];
    
        while (currentDate <= endDate) {
            let d = new Date(currentDate)
            if (d.getHours() >= 7 && (d.getHours() + d.getMinutes()/60) <= 20 && d.getDay() < 6 && d.getDay() > 0 && date[1] == null) {
                if (date[0] == null) date[0] = {
                    offer: acc._id,
                    date: d.toLocaleDateString('en'),
                    hours: []
                };
                date[0].hours.push(new Date(d).toLocaleTimeString('es-CL').substr(0,5))
            } else {
                if (date[1] == null) {
                  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
                  d.setMinutes(0);
                  currentDate = d.setHours(8);
                  date[1] = {
                    offer: acc._id,
                    date: d.toLocaleDateString('en'),
                    hours: []
                  };
                }
                date[1].hours.push(new Date(d).toLocaleTimeString('es-CL').substr(0,5))
            }
            currentDate = currentDate + acc.interval
        } 
        res.push({
            professional: acc.professional,
            specialty: acc.specialty,
            date: date
        });
    }
    return res;
}
```